# HTML minification via Gulp.js is breaking my Chart.js chart in my Angular app

Tags: angularjs, gulp, chart.js

I am just learning Gulp and trying to get it all working with my Angularjs app.

I have successfully concatenated & minified my JS files and minified my html files using the gulpfile.js below.  App works great, but my only problem is my chart does not show up after minifying my HTML.  I am using the latest version of chartjs with the Angles wrapper for angularjs. (https://github.com/lgsilver/angles)

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    ngAnnotate = require('gulp-ng-annotate'),
    minifyHTML = require('gulp-minify-html'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect'),
    htmlify = require('gulp-angular-htmlify');

// compact js
gulp.task('js', function () {
  gulp.src(['app/assets/js/**/app.js', 'app/assets/js/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(ngAnnotate())
    .pipe(uglify({mangle: false}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/js'))
});

//compact html
gulp.task('html', function() {
  gulp.src(['app/*.html', 'app/**/*.html'])
    .pipe(htmlify())
    .pipe(minifyHTML())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

**my original html**

```
    <div id="home-chart">
        <canvas barchart options="chartOptions" data="chartData" width="700" height="170"></canvas>
    </div>
```

**my minified html**

```
<div id=home-chart><canvas options=chartOptions data=chartData width=700 height=170></canvas></div>
```

I am not getting any errors, only a blank space where my bar chart should be.

Is this a problem with my javascript or the minified html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `gulp-minify-html` (or rather the module it uses [`minimize`](https://github.com/Moveo/minimize)) removes attributes without values by default.

You can easily fix that: `.pipe(minifyHTML())` => `.pipe(minifyHTML({empty: true}))`

Comment: Thank you! after looking at the docs for [minimize](https://github.com/Moveo/minimize) it looks like i could also just prepend `data-` to my `barchart` tag and that would prevent the script from removing the empty tag altogether.  That is if the Chartjs angles directive allows it.